# Creating list of model from model name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a list of models dynamically.

1. In a function, I want to pass model name as a string.
2. that model name will be used to create a list for same.
   I want this
   `List<model> lst = new();`
   I don't want this
   `List<object> lst = new();`

```
public void fxn(string modelName)
{
   //Do something to get model from modelName(not object but class)
   List<model> lst = new();
}
```

What I did:

```
public void instantiator(string modelName="test")
{
    // Get the Type object for the class
    Type type = Type.GetType(modelName);

    // Create an instance of the class using Activator.CreateInstance
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Generate the list
    List<object> x = new();
}
```

What I want:

```
public void fxn(string modelName)
{
   //Do something to get model from modelName(not object but class)
   List<model> lst = new();
}
```

Comment: Derive all models from a common interface and use a `List<myLovelyInterface>` then.

Comment: @Ralf So if I try to get list from database it throws the error like so...

Comment: "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessComponent>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<myLovelyInterface>'"
If I do something like this-
**bold** `List<myLovelyInterface> vst = (List<myLovelyInterface>)ser.Get();`
where BusinessComponent : myLovelyInterface.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you want specifically. But to get a `List<Model>` from a `string`, you can use the following code:

```
    private void CreateList(string model_name, string all_models_namespace)
    {
        /* 'model type' from location of all models, whos name matches 'model_name' */
        var model_type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(i => i.Namespace == all_models_namespace && i.Name == model_name)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        /* type of generic list List<Model> */
        var list = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(model_type);

        /* This is the instance of that specific model which was specified in the 'model_name' */
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(list);
    }
```

But it will still be of type `object`.

Comment: Is there some way I can make a generic function to infer the model through string?

Comment: we can make a way may be, if you share more about what kind of models do have. how much do they have in common. may be on StackOverFlow's chat.